# Which maps exist from the unit sphere to itself such that the image is perpendicular to the domain

Tags: functions

Which smooth maps $f:S^2\to S^2$ exist, such that $\forall x\in S^2\ \ f(x) \perp x$. I don't need surjectivity/injectivity.

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you mean by the two points $x$ and $f(x)$ being perpendicular.

Comment: @MikePierce i mean $x_1 f(x)_1 + x_2 f(x)_2 + x_3 f(x)_3 = 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If such a $f$ exists, it would define a non vanishing tangent vector field on $S^2$. This is impossible. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem